# Does the existence of a function in this proof require the axiom of choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, axiom-of-choice

I have the following proof which I think might use the axiom of choice implicitly:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a pairwise disjoint cover of a set $S\neq \emptyset$ such that $A\cap S\neq \emptyset$ for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$. Then $\vert \mathcal{A}\vert \leq \vert S\vert$, since we have an surjective function $\Phi:S\to \mathcal{A}$ by choosing for all $s\in S$ the unique set $A\in\mathcal{A}$  for which $s\in A$. It seems to me that this map is indeed well defined since the assumptions on $\mathcal{A}$ ensure such an $A$, but this feels like there is a choice being made here.

I would appreciate if someone could point out if I'm overlooking something, or just overcomplicating the argument.

Comment: You are defining a function. No choice is used there. Of course, whether $\mathcal A$ exists may use choice. But that is a different matter.

Comment: And without choice the existence of $\Phi$ does not imply the existence of an injection in the other direction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So surjectivity of $\Phi$ does not necessarily imply $\vert \mathcal{A}\vert \leq \vert S\vert$, without the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Correct. You might be interest in this [blog post] by Asaf Karagila.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course there is a use of AC here. You are proving, in effect, that if there is a surjection from $X$ onto $Y$, then there is an injection from $Y$ into $X$.

This is known as "The Partition Principle", and I have minced many a word on that topic over this site and the interwebs. It implies, for example, that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset, or that every well-ordered family of non-empty sets admits a choice function. Both of these are known to be unprovable from $\sf ZF$.

You might ask whether or not The Partition Principle implies the Axiom of Choice, that is, do we need the *full power* of AC to prove this statement. And the answer is that we do not know yet. This has been open for over a century. Very recently a proof was suggested using a new technique, but there are several significant flaws and gap in that paper, so the problem is still open.